# Let $X$ be the number of draws needed to draw the ace of spades. Find the pmf of $X$ if we draw with replacement

Tags: probability

I'm learning about PMF at the moment and it's a bit hard to grasp. Watched a bunch of videos but I want to clarify using a problem example assigned from my homework.

> 8. Cards are drawn one by one at random from a deck of cards. Let $X$ be the number of draws needed to draw the ace of spades. Find the pmf of $X$ if we draw
>      (a) with replacement and
>      (b) without replacement.

So I tried working this out by hand.

**A)** Drawing for the ace of spades with replacement means the card is put back each time it's drawn. So the chance for drawing ace of spades is consistently $1/52$. I doubt, however, the PMF is $1/52$ then, since a property of PMF is that all the probabilities must total to $1$.

I saw an example in my textbook using dice, which is arguably a replacement problem as well and the equation they gave me was this:

> **Example 2.7.** If we roll a die and let $X$ denote the number of rolls until the first $6$ appears, then Example 1.41 reveals that the pmf of $X$ is 
>   $$p(k) = P(X = k) = \frac{1}{6}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{k-1}, k = 1,2,\dotsc$$

I understand here that there is a $1/6$ chance of getting a $6$ on a roll. But why does the second part of the equation exist: $\left(\frac 56\right)^{k-1}$? Is this supposed to show that as the number of rolls goes higher and higher, the chance of getting a 6 at that specific roll grows smaller and smaller?

And if that's the case, then the graph itself as we go to infinity gets closer and closer to $0$. However, with the probability I calculated for part **a** I'll just end up getting a straight line.

Does that mean my equation then should be: $\frac{1}{52} \left(\frac{51}{52}\right)^{k-1}$?

**B)** I'm actually pretty lost here. I understand that the denominator shrinks ... so
$P(1) = 1/52 $
$P(50) = 1/2$

How do I show this in PMF?

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @Max Thank you I've never seen those! I'll put them to good use.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the dice problem, notice that it is talking about the number of trials **until** you get a six. Another way of saying this is *the number of trials until the **first** success*. Then ask yourself, what is the probability that I roll a six on the first try? Clearly, $1/6$. We look to the forumla

$$P(X = 1) = \frac{1}{6}\left(\frac56\right)^{1-1} = \frac{1}{6}$$
and it matches. What about the probability that it happens on the second trial? It must *fail* the first trial and succeed on the  second, which is $(5/6)(1/6) = 5/36$ using independence. Again, the formula gives
$$P(X = 2) = \frac{1}{6}\left(\frac56\right)^{2-1} = \frac{5}{36}$$
which matches.

So the formula in the example is saying that you fail the first $k-1$ times and the succeed on the $k$th trial.

Using similar logic, part (a) should be 
$$P(X = k) = \frac{1}{52}\left(\frac{51}{52}\right)^{k-1}\quad k\geq 1.$$

Now, the same logic applies for part (b) except, we no longer have independence since we do not put the card back. Having that in mind, what should the probabilities be? Consider $X= 1$. This means get the ace of spades on the first try. Then 
$$P(X= 1) = \frac{1}{52}.$$
If we consider $X = 2$, then this means fail on the first trial and then succeed on the second, which gives
$$P(X = 2) = \frac{51}{52}\cdot\frac{1}{51}.$$
Can you finish? What are the possible values of $k$?

Comment: It seems that it would go on until you run out of cards because of the dependency, right? Therefore, it would go like ... $\frac{1}{50}$, $\frac{1}{49}$ ... $\frac{1}{48}$ @Max

Comment: It's not clear what you're writing, but I think you have the right idea. Yes, you go until you run out. It is possible to run out because the draws are without replacement.

Comment: Okay, I believe I understand what you're getting at. Then in order to answer part B) I have to just write them all out technically or show that it would go on until running out.

Comment: Noooo, just write out like the first three or four and see if you can make a pattern. When you see a pattern, then you can write the formula for $P(X = k)$ for part (b).

Comment: Since the same logic applies, $P(X = 3) = \frac{1}{50} * \frac{51}{52}^2$, should be the next part, yes? If that is the case, then it seems like the pattern is $P(X) = \frac{1}{52 - k} * \frac{51}{52}^{k - 1}$.

Comment: No not quite. Remember, $X = 3$ means fail the first time, fail the second, and then succeed on the third. Oh, I did not bother writing the conditional probabilities because I'm "reasoning" through it, but you can use conditioning if that helps you.

Comment: Oh! So it's more like ... $\frac{51}{52} * \frac{50}{51} * \frac{1}{50}$? The way I'm reasoning through it is there is a 51/52 chance of failing the first one, and a 50/51 for failing the next one, with a 1/50 chance of succeeding the 3rd.

Comment: Yes! Notice anything???

Comment: A fraction is added each time we draw out a card (since it is non-replacement!) I'm trying to figure out the formula.

Comment: Yes, it can be tricky. But in this case, I meant notice that $\frac{51}{52}\frac{50}{51}\frac{1}{50} = \frac{1}{52}$. Very cool. Intuitively, this is like saying laying down all the cards **face down** and a table in a row. The chance that the ace of spades is in the $k$th position is $1/52$.