# Calculating Combined Standard Deviation

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation, variance

**Problem**
The standard deviation of the time you take for each statistics homework problem is 1.5 minutes, and it is 2 minutes for each chemistry problem. What is the standard deviation of the time you expect to spend on statistics and physics homework for the week if you have 5 statistics and 4 chemistry homework problems assigned?

**Analysis of the Problem**
While I haven't learned directly how to calculate combined standard deviation, I have learned about the combined variance formula that looks like this: $$V(aX + bY) = a^2(X) + b^2(Y)$$
Since we're given standard deviation in the problem, I suppose I can calculate the variance and combine the two together. This is what my setup looks like:
$$V(5S + 4C) = 5^2(1.5)^2 + 4^2(2)^2$$
This should give me the output of $$V = 120.25$$
Would it be correct to assume that the combined standard deviation then is the square root of this answer, and thus this?
$$SD = \sqrt{120.25}$$

Answer (score 1):

With one-dimensional variables like this your analysis is correct. The calculated variance is for a new random variable that is the sum of times taken for 5 statistics and 4 chemistry problems, so *by definition* its standard deviation is the square root of its variance.

However, as the chemistry and statistics answering times are independent, the correct calculation for the variance would be
$$5\times1.5^2+4\times2^2=27.25$$

Comment: Thank you! I'm very new to statistics so I want to ensure I'm learning the material correctly. I was also confused on the Combined Variance Formula given by an answer in my previous question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1889794/294276

This person says if the events are independent, then you must add the variances up one at a time instead of grouping them all up as I did in this problem. Is he correct?

@ParclyTaxel

Comment: If the events are independent and identically distributed (this appears so much in the literature that it is often abbreviated to iid without explanation), then yes, variances must be combined as separate entities; this was a trap my statistics teachers pointed out (and I got a 5 for AP Statistics!) The formula you gave is for multiples of _one_ random variable.

Comment: Ah! I think I have a better understanding of it. So in the question I listed above about getting Chemistry/Stats problems ... I wouldn't have to add them independently because I don't know if they're identically distributed, right? As opposed to the problem I linked in the URL above with scooping ice cream, which is both an independent and identically distributed event.

Comment: It is assumed in the question that the variables are iid; you can't expect each chemistry or statistics question to be done in the exact same time, right? So they should be added independently. In fact, I have edited my answer to take this into account. (And I've also got a 5 in AP Chemistry.)

Comment: Also you calculated the variance for 5 stats and **3** chem problems, instead of **4** chem problems as in the original question.